# Как уничтожить экземпляр класса в JS? Как контролировать ссылки на объект?

Tags: javascript, node.js, безопасность

Достаточно ли присвоить экземпляру класса null или undefined ?
Или для этого нужно использовать `delete varName` ?

Есть например синглтон класс,в разных участках приложения, я обращаюсь к экземпляру этого класса за данными, когда все данные получены возникает необходимость уничтожить этот экземпляр. У класса создаю функцию

```
....    
destroy(){
     instance = null;
    }
....
```

Это вообще законно?

Например в этом экземпляре класса хранились какие-то важные данные, после присвоения этому экземпляру класса `null, undefined, 0, false, '', delete varName` можно ли эти данные вытащить из памяти, в момент когда еще не все ссылки исчезли и сборщик мусора не уничтожил переменную?

Объясните как контролировать ссылки на объект и помогать сборщику мусора  его ликвидировать?
Как найти все места в коде, использующие этот объект?

Comment: https://www.frontender.info/exploring-the-abyss-of-null-and-undefined-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

`delete`, присвоение `null`, `undefined` и т.п. не имеет прямого результата в виде удаления объекта из памяти. Другими словами, вам никто не может гарантировать что объект будет удалён из памяти при выполнении вышеописанных действий.

JS удаляет объекты автоматически как только счётчик ссылок на объект (aka количество переменных, ссылающихся на объект) достигает нуля. Делается это при помощи специального механизма, который называется Garbage Сollector (процесс называется Garbage Сollection). Это внутренний механизм интерпретатора. Программист не обладает средствами прямого влияния на его работу. Например, программиста не может выполнить garbage collection по своей прихоти. Или как-то сообщить сборщику мусора, о том что вот именно этот объект нужно удалить несмотря на то что на него остались ссылки.

Если следовать некоторым рекомендациям, то вопрос отсутствия механизмов управления памятью перестаёт быть острой проблемой. Вот пара ссылок по теме:

- https://habr.com/en/post/309318/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/